# Omics vs Classic Blood Sample

Tags: blood, prevention, diagnostics

It seems to me that [omics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omics) data offers much more information than a classic biochemical blood analysis does. Are there more features that can be known from a patient blood sample using omics data in comparison with classic biochemical markers[[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_chemistry)]?

By omics data, I mean knowing all of the molecules and quantities of a blood sample.

Could integrating all the omics data associations present in databases and comparing with the blood sample say a lot about a patient's overall health?

Two examples of using omics data to get information about a patient's psychological status:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25934103
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4120773/

Many diseases are multifactorial, such as psychological ones. On the other side, some of them, such as the ones already being monitored via classical biochemical markers are not. We could then be here limited by the current concept of disease in medicine, and thus we would not gain too much with blood omics data.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @YviDe, I reformulated my question.

Comment: Hi @Carey Gregory, I reformulated my question. Is to now more clear?